# Plotting Row-wise correlation of data frame with p value

Tags: r, ggplot2, correlation

This is my dummy dataframe

```
nr1 = 4; nr2 = 8; nr3 = 6; nr = nr1 + nr2 + nr3
nc1 = 4; nc2 = 6; nc3 = 4; nc = nc1 + nc2 + nc3
mat2 = cbind(rbind(matrix(rnorm(nr1*nc1, mean = 1,   sd = 1.5), nr = nr1),
                   matrix(rnorm(nr2*nc1, mean = 0,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr2),
                   matrix(rnorm(nr3*nc1, mean = 0,   sd = 1.5), nr = nr3)),
             rbind(matrix(rnorm(nr1*nc2, mean = 0,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr1),
                   matrix(rnorm(nr2*nc2, mean = 1,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr2),
                   matrix(rnorm(nr3*nc2, mean = 0,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr3)),
             rbind(matrix(rnorm(nr1*nc3, mean = 0.5, sd = 2.5), nr = nr1),
                   matrix(rnorm(nr2*nc3, mean = 0.5, sd = 0.5), nr = nr2),
                   matrix(rnorm(nr3*nc3, mean = 1,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr3))
)
mat2 = mat2[sample(nr, nr), sample(nc, nc)] # random shuffle rows and columns
rownames(mat2) = paste0("row", seq_len(nr))
colnames(mat2) = paste0("column", seq_len(nc))
mat2 =  as.data.frame((mat2)) %>% rownames_to_column('gene')
```

I would like to know how to plot rowwise or genewise in my case correlation with significance and plot something[image] like this

Im able to calculate use this solved [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64249285/get-output-of-cor-test-as-data-frame)

My code

```
df_transpose <- mat2 %>% 
  gather(variable, value, -gene) %>% 
  spread(gene, value) %>% 
  select(-variable)

flattenCorrMatrix <- function(cormat, pmat) {
  ut <- upper.tri(cormat)
  data.frame(
    row = rownames(cormat)[row(cormat)[ut]],
    column = rownames(cormat)[col(cormat)[ut]],
    cor  =(cormat)[ut],
    p = pmat[ut]
  )
}

library(Hmisc)

res <- rcorr(as.matrix(df_transpose))

cor_matrix <- flattenCorrMatrix(res$r, res$P)
```

Now i would like to plot the way it is show in the figure attached

Im getting then calculating the `rowMedians` which is shown in y axis as this

```
medRNA <- rowMedians(as.matrix(mat2[-c(1)]))
```

Any help or suggestion would be really appreciated

The analysis im trying to reproduce is [this](https://www.huber.embl.de/users/jlu/CLL_Proteomics_public/manuscript_S1_Overview.html) publication

Comment: You have 4+8+6 = 18 rows a.k.a. genes, thus you have (18 * 17) = 153 correlation coefficients. How do you plot those against 18 rowMedians?

Comment: well that Im not sure exactly  since in the fig they labelled the no of genes and proteins in other words what other way i dont know...

Comment: @RicVillalba now I get the issue..is there way i can calculate the row-wise correlation? and their significance

Comment: That's what you're doin in `cor_matrix <- flattenCorrMatrix(res$r, res$P)`. That part works fine

Comment: But using that I can;t plot with those medians as the median length won't match ..perhpas